# Issues reading/writing images

Tags: java, spring, image, thymeleaf, aes

I have been working on code to encrypt and decrypt images via a Spring webapp in which i use Thymeleaf. I have tested each method involved in the process and each one is sound. The way the process flows is supposed to be:

User1 uploads image and key, app breaks down image into pixels and then into 128-bit stateHexes, stateHexes are encrypted using AES, and rebuilt into encrypted image to be displayed to User1 for download. User1 then sends image to User2 who then downloads image and decrypts it using the same process.

When I treat it like the above scenario the image somehow changes after storing it. However, if i treat it as follows the file encrypts and decrypts perfectly.

So I assume the issue must lie in either saving the file or retrieving the file, or some other issue pertaining to file handling.

Below I will show code snippets of how i load and save the images.

This is how I get the image

```
          // Get the filename and path for the image passed in from user
      Path fileNameandPath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, file.getOriginalFilename());

      // Generate the file and write the image onto it
      File imageFile = fileNameandPath.toFile();
      BufferedImage image = null;
      try {
        Files.write(fileNameandPath, file.getBytes());
        image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        Files.delete(fileNameandPath);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("COULDNT READ IMAGE AT = " + fileNameandPath);
      }
```

And this is how I create the outputImage

```
    String outputFilePath = new File("src/main/resources/static").getAbsolutePath()  + "\\output.jpg";
    File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath);
    try {
      outputFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("FILE ALREADY EXISTS");
    }

    // Write the image to the outputfile
    try {
      ImageIO.write(outputImage, "jpg", outputFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I pass in an all black image (each pixel's hex code is 000000) and it reads the image and encrypts as expected, but when decrypting it reads in the previous image wrong, leading me to believe that it's not the code but most likely how the file is stored/retrieved? I only have one guess: that somehow the file is getting mixed up. If anyone has any clues as to why this happening, any help or leads would be appreciated.

I think it may have to do with how I write to the image. Reading the image is no problem, but how I write to the image seems to alter it in a way.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some sleep, I realized that because I need the image to remain the same when reading and writing, I was losing bits of the image due to the lossy nature of .jpg files. Now that I save my file as a .png I get no errors. Hope this helps someone down the road!